# Как выполнить разные функции, при событии на одном элементе?

Tags: javascript

Суть проблемы такова. Есть кнопка,  при первом клике на неё я хочу выполнить одну функцию, при втором другую. Но проблема в том, что при первом клике выполняются обе функции. Как можно это решить ? Ниже упрощенный пример для понимания:

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
 this.classList.toggle('active');
});
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 if(e.target.classList.contains('active')) {
   console.log('Hello');
  } else {
   return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<button class="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: вам нужно активировать\деактивировать кнопку, типа кнопка плей\пауза ?

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych Нет, хочу при клике добавить родительский элемент в список и подсветить кнопку, а при втором клике удалить элемент из списка, что-то вроде favorites

Comment: так проверяйте, есть ли элемент в списке и действуйте соответственно, и не надо 2-ва хэндлера

Comment: Сохраняйте состояние и создайте один обработчик, который анализирует состояние и вызывает что нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно в зависимости от класса выполнить функцию, то можно вот так переключать класс при клике через один обработчик события:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn')

btn.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.classList.contains('active'))
    console.log('Hello')
  else
    console.log('Bye')
  
  target.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```html
<button class="btn">Click</button>
```

В зависимости от переменной, просто переменная toggle переключается на противоположное булевое значение.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn')
let toggle = false

btn.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (toggle)
    console.log('Hello')
  else
    console.log('Bye')
  
  toggle = !toggle
})
```

```html
<button class="btn">Click</button>
```

В зависимости от номера клика, используется удаление первого элемента через shift, функции которые можно вызвать представлены в виде массиве элементов из массивов, где каждый такой элемент первым индексом содержит ссылку на функцию, остальными сами аргументы.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn')
const call = [
  [console.log, 'Hello', 'Mr. pi4yyy'], 
  [console.log, 'Bye'], 
  [console.log, 'Last function']
]

btn.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  const shift = call.shift()
  
  if (!shift)
    return console.log('Не осталось функций')
  
  shift[0](...shift.slice(1))
})
```

```html
<button class="btn">Click</button>
```